Recursion - Not Returning Values as Expected
I'm currently writing a program to return all additions to a number subtracted from itself (For example, if 3 were the number, the output should be 6 (3+2+1).  Essentially, I'm trying to have the function return the permutation of a number, but with addition, instead of mulitplication.  This seemed like a perfect situation for a recursive function (something I struggling to understand).  In my function, I would expect that the return value is not relevant (during the while loop) as the information is directly contained in the variables (specifically, static b).  Yet, when I change the while loop in my function, to anything other than b, the wrong value gets returned from the function, into main() - it's always 0.  What's even more confusing is that when I do a printf of b, right before the return of the (second - outside of while loop) b return value, my function prints the correct value (regardless of the return value above).  Why must my function return b in the while loop (first return function) for the function to return the correct value, which is 55 (10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1+0)?
As the code is below, it works correctly.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
    
int sumyears(int a)
{
    static int b=0;
    while(a>0)
    {
        b+=a;
        sumyears(a-1);
        return b;  //Program works correctly when I return b, but not when I return any other value, including a
    }
    printf("%d", b); //Program will always print correct value, but return different values based upon the return value in the while loop
    return b;
}
    
int main()
{
    printf("%d", sumyears(10));
}


return all additions to a number subtracted from itself - I have no idea what you're even trying to achieve.

It's difficult to explain, but I'm trying to have a function, which takes a number and adds it to itself, while subtracting 1 each time.  It's basically a permutation calculation, except with addition.  For example, if 4 is the input, the function output would be 10 (4+3+2+1+0).

Presentation: A blob of words isn't great reading.

"I'm currently writing a program" -- you are not fooling anyone, this is homework. And the proper thing to do on stackoverflow is to state that your question is about homework.

Nope, I wish I were a student - that boat sailed over a decade ago.  I'm an accountant attempting to write a program that can handle depreciation, hence the sumofyears() function.  Sum of years is a depreciation method.

@MikeNakis Why the pessimism? When I was 12-13-14-15, I was also writing random little programs, and I was also annoying people on the German java-forum with questions about programs that had no obvious practical use. Those were not homework either. I learned a lot.

Why must my function return b in the while loop (first return function) for the function to return the correct value,  as you have stored value in static variable b to retain or keep its value in subsequent calls, you would want to return something you have stored. Because your result is stored in b, returning anything other than that would not give you intended output. Of course, this is not the best method, learning still worth it.

Okay guys, my bad. I am sorry. Welcome to the wonderful work of programming, Ratdude.


seemed like a perfect situation for a recursive function (something I struggling to understand)

You want to compute the sum of all integers up to n.

If n == 0, then the sum is obviously 0

Otherwise:
(0 + 1 + ... + n) = (0 + 1 + ... + (n - 1)) + n

 sumOfIntsUpTo(n) =   sumOfIntsUpTo(n - 1)  + n



As a recursive function:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int sumIntsUpTo(int a) {
  return (a <= 0) ? 0 : (sumIntsUpTo(a - 1) + a);
}
int main() {
  printf("%d", sumIntsUpTo(10));
}


There is of course a well known explicit formula for that.
I don't know where you got the idea of using static inside of recursive functions, but I'd suggest to discard this source (delete the link / burn the book / don't talk to the weird person who suggested that). When you're trying to write down a recursive definition, the absolutely last thing that you want to deal with is some global mutable state accessed by each invocation of this function (unless you're generating names... and a couple of other valid use cases that you shouldn't worry about for now).

also report to the police the person who suggested that.

Understanding Recursion with and without Static Variables
Recursion works like a stack, where each recursive call creates a new stack frame. In this explanation, we'll look at two approaches to understanding recursion—one using a static variable and one without.
Approach 1: Without Static Variables
Consider the following recursive method that calculates the sum of integers from a down to 1:
public int doSum(int a) {
    if (a == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    int result = a + doSum(a - 1);
    return result;
}

Let's trace the execution with a = 3:

Initial Call: doSum(3)

result = 3 + doSum(2)

Recursive Call: doSum(2)

result = 2 + doSum(1)

Base Case: doSum(1)

Returns 1

Back to doSum(2)

result = 2 + 1
Returns 3

Back to doSum(3)

result = 3 + 3
Returns 6
The key idea here is that each recursive call returns a value that is used in the previous call. Each function call has its own separate instance of local variables (result in this case).
Approach 2: With Static Variables
In this approach, we'll use a static variable to accumulate the sum:
static int b = 0;
public void accumulateSum(int a) {
    if (a == 0) {
        return;
    }
    b = b + a;
    accumulateSum(a - 1);
}

Tracing the execution with a = 2:

Initial Call: accumulateSum(2)

b = 0 + 2
Recursive Call: accumulateSum(1)

Recursive Call: accumulateSum(1)

b = 2 + 1
Recursive Call: accumulateSum(0)

Base Case: accumulateSum(0)

Returns (No change to b)
After execution, b will hold the accumulated sum of 2 + 1, which is 3.
Key Differences
Non-static Variables: Each recursive call has its own separate instance of the local variables. Values must be returned and passed through the recursion chain.
Static Variables: The variable is shared across all recursive calls. Its value is updated globally, so it retains changes across different calls.
Understanding both approaches is crucial. Non-static recursion relies on passing and returning values, while static recursion directly modifies a shared state.

Thank you for this, it was extremely helpful.  Having the result function at the begining of the statement makes a lot more sense than omiting it.  Effectively, you're returning the function into the variable itself.
